# UITextField in UIAlertController text is NULL and doesn't show any text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have presented an UIAlertController with textfield but whenever I type there's nothing on textfield and gets warning like requesting caretRectForPosition: while the NSTextStorage has oustanding changes {0, 0}.
My Code is

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
   // textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    //textField.delegate = self;
}];

UIAlertAction *confirmAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
    UITextField * cardField = textfields[0];
    NSLog(@"Current password %@", [cardField text]);

    if ([cardField hasText]) {
        //will do something
    }
}];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    NSLog(@"Canelled");
}];

[alertController addAction:confirmAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and error is `requesting caretRectForPosition: while the NSTextStorage has oustanding changes {0, 0}`

Comment: This code worked for me all fine and Current password .. prints whatever i enter in the textfield. I had to just append @ next to all button title and placeholder like @"placeholder" and @"ok". Can you give more information of the view controller which is presenting the UIAlertController? It may be the presenting controller giving the issue.

Comment: me to get the exact result, what was the issue u faced

Comment: Tried your whole code, works perfectly.

Comment: I think the viewcontroller is causing the problem.

Comment: This crash is mostly happen when the textview is limited to have fixed length string (condition is set in delegate method), after pasting a lot of text into the textview, then deleting a few characters, and then writing new ones, causing the above problem.

Comment: Can you check your whole project including used libraries to see if there is any subclass/extension of NSTextStorage?